# umbraco back-end login not working in FireFox

Tags: .net, firefox, iis, cookies, umbraco

Today we started to experience the issue with logging in to the Umbraco using FireFox - after pressing the login button the login page just refreshes with no error. Login is working correctly in IE, Opera, Safari and Chrome.

After the investigation, I have found that the reason is that FireFox is not accepting the umbraco cookies.

After pressing login I see this response

[image]

but this cookie is not present in the next request.

I have checked the following:

- Cookie permissions in FireFox.
- Domain name doesn't contain underscores.
- App_Browsers folder contains the browser file that enables the cookies for all browsers.

Any suggestion and help will be appreciated.

Environment configuration

- Windows Server 2008
- IIS 7
- .NET 4
- Umbraco 4.7.1
- FireFox 15

Thanks

UPDATE 06/09/2012

Here is I found exactly the same issue with the resolution, but **this didn't work for me**, maybe somebody will be more lucky :)

Detailed Issue desctiption:
Using fiddler is shows the URL request to /umbraco/umbraco.aspx/ then immediately goes to the /umbraco/logout.aspx?redir=%2fumbraco%2fumbraco.aspx%2f  which takes you back to the login screen.

Solution:
Well, I figured out the issue.  When entering the HTTP Redirect on IIS 7.5 be very careful on how you do that.   I had originally put the redirect address for when someone enters http://login.myurlhere.com/

to point to the following

http://www.myurlhere.com/umbraco/umbraco.aspx

This was done in an attempt to give the end users a simple way to access the login screen.   It seemed it was stuck in a loop so instead of that address I pointed it to http://www.myurlhere.com/umbraco/login.aspx and in the box below there for Redirect behavior (which I believe is the key) I checked the "Redirect all requests to the exact destination (instead of relative to destination)"   This has since fixed my problems in both FF/IE/Chrome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify that the server date/time is the same as the workstation time/date? I've had weird problems like this before when they are out of sync.

In fact, it looks like in the header above you show a date of 9/8, and the cookie is supposed to expire on 9/6...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have checked the dates and they seems to be correct. About the [date] header - this is date for the cache, I have attached the screenshot from Fiddler2 to make it more readable